Get the full Directory Path of Application Server using Value Help in Selection Screen
Here's the requirement, I want to get the Directory path and populate that in the Selection Screen Parameter of my report. But I don't see any standard Function Module to get the path, as it always asks to select a File in it. I don't want to select a file, I want to choose a Directory like '\10.9.18.16\B2B_INTERFACES\TO_PROCESS'
I tried using below FM's but none of them helped me to choose a directory.

RZL_READ_DIR_LOCAL
J_2GSERVER_FILES_F4
/SAPDMC/LSM_F4_SERVER_FILE
EPS_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING and EPS_GET_DIRECTORY_PATH
SUBST_GET_FILE_LIST
TMP_GUI_DIRECTORY_LIST_FILES
RS_GET_F4_DIR_FROM_APPLSERV

Report reads from AL11 (USER_DIR table) which is of no use
And a SUBMIT call on report:
SUBMIT rs_get_f4_dir_from_applserv AND RETURN.
IMPORT path_name FROM MEMORY ID 'PATH_NAME_SDL'.




F4_DXFILENAME_TOPRECURSION


The transaction AL11 uses C calls for this. They are wrapped up in the perform fill_file_list in the program rswatch0. It doesn't return the file_list, but you could dirty assign it after you call it.

On the app server:
it is generally not done, to offer the ability to expose all directories the SAPADM user can write to.
You could destroy the SAP system with that kind of access.
Perhaps a compromise:
You could write a customer f4 Value help to provide a Set of reasonable options.
REPORT zf4dir.
PARAMETERS: p_dir TYPE string.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_dir.
  PERFORM get_app_server_directories.

FORM get_app_server_directories.
  DATA: lt_directories TYPE TABLE OF ddshretval,
        ls_directory   TYPE ddshretval.


  ls_directory-fieldname = 'DIR'.

  ls_directory-fieldval = '/usr/sap/trans'.
  APPEND ls_directory TO lt_directories.

  ls_directory-fieldval = '/usr/sap/tmp'.
  APPEND ls_directory TO lt_directories.

  ls_directory-fieldval = '/usr/sap/data'.
  APPEND ls_directory TO lt_directories.


 CALL FUNCTION 'F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST'
   EXPORTING
     retfield        = 'FIELDVAL'
     dynpprog        = sy-cprog
     dynpnr          = sy-dynnr
     dynprofield     = 'P_DIR'
     value_org       = 'S'
     window_title    = 'App Server Directories'
   TABLES
  value_tab       = lt_directories
EXCEPTIONS
  parameter_error = 1
  no_values_found = 2
  OTHERS          = 3.


ENDFORM.

For the Client:
See cl_gui_frontend_services=>directory_browse
PARAMETERS: p_pcdir TYPE string DEFAULT 'c:\temp\'



AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_pcdir.

cl_gui_frontend_services=>directory_browse(
  EXPORTING
     window_title         = 'Directory for bla bla'
     initial_folder       = 'C:\temp'
  CHANGING
     selected_folder      = p_pcdir    
   EXCEPTIONS
     OTHERS               = 4  ).


Usually, SAP way of saving anything to the app server is via Logical Paths. That's described in SAP doco. It is required from both auditing and SAP Security Programming points of view.
Then you use search help H_FILEPATH to get the logical file path and afterwards you render the file path using FM FILE_GET_NAME_AND_LOGICAL_PATH.
